# MySQL multi update error

Tags: mysql

I have joined three tables into a view, and then i try to update the view and get this error

```
#1393 - Can not modify more than one base table through a join view

ER_VIEW_MULTIUPDATE
```

I understand the error. I cannot update multiple tables at once.

HOWEVER... I have done this before. Last week to be precise, on the same machine, same mysql installation.

I promise you that I have joined together tables through a view before (the same tables infact) and updated the view with no problems.

Does anybody know why its not working?

## The PHP code that worked last week

```
"UPDATE administrators AS a INNER JOIN user_types AS ut ON a.admin_id = ut.type_id INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = ut.user_id SET a.firstname = '{$user_input["firstname"]}', a.surname = '{$user_input["surname"]}', u.email_address = '{$user_input["email_address"]}' WHERE u.user_id = {$user_input["user_id"]}"
```

## The SQL code im trying now

```
CREATE VIEW admin_users AS
SELECT administrators ad
    JOIN user_types ut
        ON ad.admin_id = ut.type_reference
    JOIN users us
        ON ut.user_id = us.user_id
WHERE ut.user_type = 'ADMIN'

UPDATE admin_users
SET
    firstname = 'alex2',
    surname = 'finch2',
    email_address = 'test@hotmail.co.uk'
WHERE
    user_id = 2
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post some code. The SQL for the view and for the `UPDATE` query. I'm guessing your `UPDATE` is modifying fields that belong to more than one table, but no way to tell without seeing some code.

Comment: Please post the update SQL you used last week ! :)

Comment: It may be a permission problem with one of the tables and the user you are using today, which may be different from the user you used "last week".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL that worked last week was a direct `UPDATE` query that modified tables, whereas you're now attempting to `UPDATE` those same tables through a view. That's the change. With a `VIEW`, you can only update one table at a time. You might look into stored procedures if you want to update multiple tables with one query.

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updateUser(
    var_user_id INT,
    var_firstname VARCHAR(32),
    var_surname VARCHAR(32),
    var_email_address VARCHAR(128)
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE administrators AS a 
        INNER JOIN user_types AS ut 
            ON a.admin_id = ut.type_id 
        INNER JOIN users AS u 
            ON u.user_id = ut.user_id 
        SET a.firstname = var_firstname, 
            a.surname = var_surname, 
            u.email_address = var_email_address 
    WHERE u.user_id = var_user_id;
END//
```

To call:

```
CALL updateUser( '$user_id', '$firstname', '$surname', '$email_address' );
```

Comment: Ahh... I only really made the view so the code was more readable. Thanks